# "Error: ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type." in Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am getting errors exporting and getting the image URL for an image. Here is the image I am trying to export:

```
    img = an_image.add(another_img)
```

I have tried 'ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive'

```
    export_params = {
    "image": img,
    "description": 'LST',
    "folder": "imageEE",
    "scale": 10,
    "region": geometry,
    "crs": 'EPSG:4326',
    "maxPixels": 1e12,
    "fileFormat": 'GeoTIFF',
    "formatOptions": {
    "cloudOptimized": True
    }}

# Export the image to Google Drive
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**export_params)
task.start()
```

and I have tried 'ee.getDownloadURL()' as per the example given: https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/py/Image/download.py

```
URL = img.getDownloadUrl({
    'name': 'final_img',
    'scale': 10,
    'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
    'region': geometry
})
```

Both cases give me the same/similar errors to do with the image input

```
Error: ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type. Expected type: 
List<Image<unknown bands>>. Actual type: Image<[B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B8A, B9, 
B10, B11, B12, QA10, QA20, QA60]>. (Error code: 3)
enter code here
```

The same code exports the image when using the Google Earth Engine editor in JavaScript so I need to know how to pass the image parameter in Python. The task gets submitted (can see it in my task manager ) but gives me the error given above so it does not get saved.

<<< updated example >>>

full error for the getDownloadURL case:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py", line 337, in _execute_cloud_call
    return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/thumbnails?fields=name&alt=json returned "ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type.
Expected type: List<Image<unknown bands>>.
Actual type: Image<[SR_B1, SR_B2, SR_B3, SR_B4, SR_B5, SR_B6, SR_B7, SR_QA_AEROSOL, ST_B10, ST_ATRAN, ST_CDIST, ST_DRAD, ST_EMIS, ST_EMSD, ST_QA, ST_TRAD, ST_URAD, QA_PIXEL, QA_RADSAT]>.". Details: "ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type.
Expected type: List<Image<unknown bands>>.
Actual type: Image<[SR_B1, SR_B2, SR_B3, SR_B4, SR_B5, SR_B6, SR_B7, SR_QA_AEROSOL, ST_B10, ST_ATRAN, ST_CDIST, ST_DRAD, ST_EMIS, ST_EMSD, ST_QA, ST_TRAD, ST_URAD, QA_PIXEL, QA_RADSAT]>.">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\RP3\Code\thermal\final\code\main.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\RP3\Code\thermal\final\code\main.py", line 16, in main
    recent_thermal_img = model(l_collection_recentimg,  s2_collection_recentimg, extent)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\RP3\Code\thermal\final\code\allmodel.py", line 185, in model
    path = img.getDownloadUrl({
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\deprecation.py", line 32, in Wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\image.py", line 469, in getDownloadURL
    return data.makeDownloadUrl(data.getDownloadId(request))
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py", line 1159, in getDownloadId
    result = _execute_cloud_call(
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py", line 339, in _execute_cloud_call
    raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)
ee.ee_exception.EEException: ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type.
Expected type: List<Image<unknown bands>>.
Actual type: Image<[SR_B1, SR_B2, SR_B3, SR_B4, SR_B5, SR_B6, SR_B7, SR_QA_AEROSOL, ST_B10, ST_ATRAN, ST_CDIST, ST_DRAD, ST_EMIS, ST_EMSD, ST_QA, ST_TRAD, ST_URAD, QA_PIXEL, QA_RADSAT]>.
```

full error for the export to drive case:

same as before

more code for making the image:

````
    ```...    

        im1 = L8_LST_30m.subtract(L8_LST_MODEL)

palette = ['040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6', \
            '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef'] \

# Define a gaussian kernel
gaussian = ee.Kernel.gaussian(**{
    'radius': 2, 
    'units': 'pixels'
})

im2 = im1.resample("bicubic").convolve(gaussian)

visParam_residuals = {
    'min': -10,
    'max': 9,
    'palette': ['blue', 'yellow', 'red']
}

im3 = ee.Image(inter2).add(sNDVI.multiply(S2_1)) \
            .add(sNDBI.multiply(S2_2)).add(sNDWI.multiply(S2_3))


img = im3.add(im2)```
````

the inputs to the model function are strings:

```
LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2/LC09_178027_20230314
COPERNICUS/S2/20230327T083601_20230327T084622_T36TXT
```

which get converted to collections and then clipped or first() depending on what needs to be done.

Comment: Please post a complete example. The error clearly indicates the problem is elsewhere in your script.

Comment: @NoelGorelick I added some additional info, let me know if you need more

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main error you are getting:

```bash
Error: ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type. Expected type: 
List<Image<unknown bands>>. Actual type: Image<[B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B8A, B9, 
B10, B11, B12, QA10, QA20, QA60]>. (Error code: 3)
```

comes from an incorrect use of `ee.ImageCollection.fromImages` .

Consider the following example:

```py
img1 = ee.Image(0)
img2 = ee.Image(1)
img3 = ee.Image(2)

# Error: passing a single image instead of a list of images:
print(
ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(img1).getInfo()
)

# Ok: passing a list consisting of a single image:
print(
ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([img1]).getInfo()
)

# Ok: passing a list consisting of more than one images:
print(
ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([img1,img2,img3]).getInfo()
)
```

Example in the code editor: https://code.earthengine.google.com/89b7cbcecee53f10b21dcc12b19ff342

As you didn't post a complete minimal working example, I can only guess that this is the error in your code.